# Mongoose Work only first time but doesn't works second time onwards

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, mongoose, nosql

Below is the Code:

```
import mongoose from "mongoose"
const testingScript = async () => {
    for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      console.log("Index", i);
      mongoose.connect('URL');
      
      var connection = mongoose.connection;
      
      connection.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));
      connection.once('open', function () {
      
          connection.db.collection("test", function(err, collection){
              collection.find({abc: "12345"}).toArray(function(err, data){
                  console.log(data); // it will print your collection data
              })
          });
      
      });

    }
  };

  testingScript()
```

Below is code for Mongoose Schema that is saved in DB.

```
import { Schema, model, Document, Types, Mongoose } from "mongoose";

const userSchema = new Schema(
  {
    name: {type: String},
    email: {type: String},
    deletedAt: { type: Date, default: null },
    schema_version: { type: Number, default: 1 },
  },
  {
    timestamps: true,
  }
);


export interface IUser extends Document {
  _id: string;
  name: string;
  email: string;
  createdAt: Date;
  updatedAt?: Date;
  deletedAt?: Date;
  schema_version: number;
}
const user = model<IUser>("User", userSchema);
```

For the first `POST` request, it will get all the records but afterward, it will get only one record. Moreover after the second request, even `GET` doesn't return anything from DB.

Comment: Hi, if you came up with a solution please tell me <3